# Grouping several columns with the same category into one table in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, count, pandas-groupby, categorical-data

i have dataset like this

| Feature Name | Description | Data Type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| customerID | Contains customer ID | unique ID, categorical, nominal |
| OnlineSecurity | Whether the customer has online security or not (Yes, No, No internet service) | categorical, nominal |
| OnlineBackup | Whether the customer has online backup or not (Yes, No, No internet service) | categorical, nominal |
| DeviceProtection | Whether the customer has device protection or not (Yes, No, No internet service) | categorical, nominal |
| TechSupport | Whether the customer has tech support or not (Yes, No, No internet service) | categorical, nominal |
| streamingTV | Whether the customer has streaming TV or not (Yes, No, No internet service) | categorical, nominal |
| streamingMovies | Whether the customer has streaming movies or not (Yes, No, No internet service) | categorical, nominal |
| Contract | The contract term of the customer (Month-to-month, One year, Two year) | categorical, nominal |
| PaperlessBilling | Whether the customer has paperless billing or not (Yes, No) | categorical, nominal |
| PaymentMethod | The customer’s payment method (Electronic check, Mailed check, Bank transfer, Credit card) | categorical, nominal |
| MonthlyCharges | The amount charged to the customer monthly | numeric , float |
| TotalCharges | The total amount charged to the customer | numeric, float |
| Churn | Whether the customer churned or not (Yes or No) | categorical, nominal |

the dataset are from [kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/blastchar/telco-customer-churn)

as you can see, `OnlineSecurity`, `OnlineBackup`, `DeviceProtection`, `TechSupport`,`streamingTV`, `StreamingMovies` have same category ["yes", "No", "No internet service]. I want to groupby all those columns with the expected result like this :

|  | Yes | No | No internet service |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| OnlineSecurity | 3497 | 1520 | 2015 |
| DeviceProtection | 3497 | 1520 | 2015 |
| TechSupport | 3497 | 1520 | 2015 |
| streamingTV | 3497 | 1520 | 2015 |
| streamingTV | 3497 | 1520 | 2015 |
| StreamingMovies | 3497 | 1520 | 2015 |

the number in above table is just random value, i want it to be counting every value in each category for every columns

Comment: post the data as text/code and not as an image

Comment: ok, i already changed that

Comment: still no real data, you're posting information about your columns in your frame.

Comment: the dataset is too big, i added kagle link where i got the dataset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find the table you posted above in the link but I suppose you have it. I copied it into a `metadata` file.

```
# load the data into df and metadata
df = pd.read_csv('WA_Fn-UseC_-Telco-Customer-Churn.csv')
metadata = pd.read_csv('WA_Fn-UseC_-Telco-Customer-Churn_meta.csv')
```

Then you will have to get the columns which have the same category.

```
cols = metadata.loc[metadata['Description'].str.contains('Yes, No, No internet service')]['Feature Name'].tolist()
```

Here we check for rows that has `Yes, No, No internet service` in the columns which gives us: `['OnlineSecurity', 'OnlineBackup', 'DeviceProtection', 'TechSupport', 'StreamingTV', 'StreamingMovies']`

Then I choose to melt the `df` with the selected columns and group them with `groupby` and count the values.

```
results = (df
    .melt(value_vars=cols)
    .groupby(['variable', 'value'])
    .agg({'value': 'count'})
    .unstack()
    .reset_index()
    .droplevel(level=0, axis=1)
)
```

This gives you the output:

|  | No | No internet service | Yes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| DeviceProtection | 3095 | 1526 | 2422 |
| OnlineBackup | 3088 | 1526 | 2429 |
| OnlineSecurity | 3498 | 1526 | 2019 |
| StreamingMovies | 2785 | 1526 | 2732 |
| StreamingTV | 2810 | 1526 | 2707 |
| TechSupport | 3473 | 1526 | 2044 |

(comment below asked for a total column)

```
results = (df
    .melt(value_vars=cols)
    .groupby(['variable', 'value'])
    .agg({'value': 'count'})
    .unstack()
    .reset_index()
    .droplevel(level=0, axis=1)
    .assign(total = lambda x: x.sum(axis=1))
)
```

Comment: yes, i dont list all the variables in my post because its too big but the dataset that i have is the same like in the link, i tried your code `cols = metadata.loc[metadata['Description'].str.contains('Yes, No, No internet service')]['Feature Name'].tolist()` it give me an error `KeyError: 'Description'`

Comment: but i skipped this `cols = metadata.loc[metadata['Description'].str.contains('Yes, No, No internet service')]['Feature Name'].tolist()` 

and write the service variables manually `cols = ['OnlineSecurity', 'OnlineBackup', 'DeviceProtection', 'TechSupport', 'StreamingTV' , 'StreamingMovies']`, it works. Thank you

Comment: can you add total column at the right side of the table with this code ?

Comment: Yes, you can add `assign()` to the results chain.